# colorbox - page loaded, images in it not load as colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

i have question about colorbox.

I have this script for load page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // ColorBox
    $("a[rel='colorbox']").colorbox({
        close: "Zavřít",
        current: "Obrázek {current} z {total}",
        next: "Další",
        previous: "Předchozí"
    });

    // ColorBox - Module
    $(".load").colorbox({
        close: "Zavřít",
        fixed: true,
        maxHeight: $(window).height() - 80,
        opacity: 0.75,
        top: 30,
        width: $(window).width() - 100
    });

});
```

It loads fine in colorbox but i have images in loaded page and i want them load in colorbox too.

Any help, please?

Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE:**

I tried:

```
$(".load").colorbox({
    close: "Zavřít",
    fixed: true,
    maxHeight: $(window).height() - 80,
    opacity: 0.75,
    top: 30,
    width: $(window).width() - 100,
    onComplete: function(){
        $("a[rel='colorbox']").colorbox({
            close: "Zavřít",
            current: "Obrázek {current} z {total}",
            next: "Další",
            previous: "Předchozí"
        });
    }
});
```

It's better. Image try to load but there are some mistakes. When i click to image to load it in colorbox, it starts loading but image not load (not display, still loading image). If i click to next or previous, it works (image display), but current title is still same and colorbox works strangely (position, click area around for close and key shortcuts don't work).

There is an example (AKCE - SHOW): http://rene-pastor.vf-fans.net/jitka-valkova/

Answer (score 0):

Since the images inside the loaded page colorbox are being loaded after the DOM is ready you will need to attach the $.colorbox() to them after they are loaded using the onComplete callback like this:

```
$(".load").colorbox({
    close: "Zavřít",
    fixed: true,
    maxHeight: $(window).height() - 80,
    opacity: 0.75,
    top: 30,
    width: $(window).width() - 100,
    onComplete : function(){
        $("a[rel='colorbox']").colorbox({
            close: "Zavřít",
            current: "Obrázek {current} z {total}",
            next: "Další",
            previous: "Předchozí"
        });
    }
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It's better. Image try to load but there are some mistakes. When i click to image to load it in colorbox, it starts loading but image not load (not display, still loading image). If i click to next or previous, it works (image display), but current title is still same and colorbox works strangely.

Any help?

Comment: You may be better off loading the content via $.load into an absolute positioned div and then loading colorbox from the image clicks instead of doing double colorboxes. I can update the answer if this is the route you want to go.

Comment: I will welcome any help. But i like features of colorbox (close button, esc or click outside the content to close, etc.).